# Async Context Manager that performs an action on context switch

Tags: python, asynchronous, contextmanager

I would like to make a context manager for async functions that calls a function every time the execution "moves" to another context

E.g.

```
import os
import asyncio

class AsyncContextChangeDir:
    def __init__(self, newdir):
        self.curdir = os.getcwd()
        self.newdir = newdir

    async def __aenter__(self):
        os.chdir(self.newdir)

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.curdir)

async def workon_mypath():
    async with AsyncContextChangeDir("/tmp"):
        print("working in /tmp context manager, cwd:" + os.getcwd()) # /mypath
        await asyncio.sleep(100)
        print("working in /tmp context manager, cwd:" + os.getcwd()) # ???

async def workon_someotherpath():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    os.chdir("/home")
    print("working in other context cwd:" + os.getcwd())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    workon_mypath(),
    workon_someotherpath()))
```

I would like the second print to print `/mypath`, and obviously to restore the previous working directory every time the execution "switches" to another context

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what you might expect from the name, context managers as a concept don't have anything to do with context switches.

Neither regular context managers nor asynchronous context managers are informed about event loop "context switches". There is no way for a context manager to detect that the event loop is going to start running another coroutine, and there is no way for a context manager to execute code when that happens.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any other construct that can achieve the desired behaviour?
Do coroutines have any way to detect that the event loop is going to start running another coroutine?

Comment: @Recursing: You might be able to do it by modifying the event loop, or by implementing a special coroutine that executes registered callbacks every time it yields or resumes, but `async` syntax wouldn't be enough to implement it, and it's a dangerous, bug-prone design anyway.

Comment: So there is no standard way to detect a "context switch"? I'm surprised it's not considered a useful feature